# Numbering same level text in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I Have the following issue . I have text at same level , but the numbers showing are not sequential. I can manually change the numbering to make it sequential. But as you see clicking on them they seem to be of different sequence altogether. How do I get them in the same sequence?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Select all the things you want to be numbered
2. Click the numbered list button in the ribbon
3. Voila! A single numbered list!

Comment on this if it doesn't work.

Comment: That option doesn't come up when I select all. I only get the below options [link]http://imgur.com/a/Xmb1E[/link]

Comment: @misguided Are you looking in the tool ribbon? I'm talking about the thing at the top of the screen with tabs like Home, View, Review, etc. This should be in the Home tab.